Usage of なだけで in this context?

What does this usage of なだけで mean here exactly?
I understand the sentence is akin to
"it felt like he was watching the situation from a higher point of view"
And then in the bottom panel:
"But that's normal"
"Because I luckily was able to live a normal life..."
平気なだけで
From context I can gather it seems to be akin to "I'm alright because"..

Well, yes > "I'm alright because (luckily I've had a normal life)".  Other than that, I guess no one who doesn't know the story can tell what exactly is meant.

俺が運よく平凡に生きてこれたから平気なだけで（あって）、それが普通なんだろうか。


だけで is the te-form of だけだ. It's in the te-form probably because it's an 言いさし文.
(な)だけだ here is "It's just that ～" or "It's simply that ～". See this answer for similar examples.


俺が運良く平凡に生きてこれたから平気なだけで…
It may be simply that I feel nothing because I've been lucky enough to live an ordinary life...

